# laravel + mix + vue router error: export 'createStaticVNode' (imported as '_createStaticVNode') was not found

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, laravel-mix

Hello i'm new to laravel and mix. for now i'm getting through jeffrey way vue tutorial. this course caused many issues. what made me confused and somehow disappointed is new problem. in episode 26 ([there](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26)) when i tried to run watch command that threw a new error:

> WARNING in ./resources/assets/js/views/Home.vue?vue&type=template&id=6c0a33b2 (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26).rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/assets/js/views/Home.vue?vue&type=template&id=6c0a33b2) 6:30-48

> export 'createStaticVNode' (imported as '_createStaticVNode') was not found in 'vue' (possible exports: default)

could anyone help me?

EDIT:

contents of project files:

route.js (assets/js):

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home')
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Home.vue (assets/js/views):

```
<template> 
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class='panel panel-default'>
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Home page
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example compnoent!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello world!'
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

app.js (used as entry point, saved in assets/js)

```
import './bootstrap';

import router from './routes'; 

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    router
})
```

bootstrap.js (assets/js):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);
window.axios = axios;

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] =     'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Comment: Show your `Home.vue` and `routes.js` files

Comment: @SarwarAhmed post is updated!

Comment: what `Vue` version have you used?

Comment: Did you try to add `.default` at the end of requiring  `component: require('./views/Home').default`?

Comment: @SarwarAhmed vue version is 2.6.14. yes i have tried that and not worked!

Answer (score 0):

> route.js (assets/js):

> import router from './routes';

You said your router file name `route.js` but you imported `routes`! Make sure your file name is correct or import correctly.

Comment: thank you mr Ahmed. i think it was version conflict problem. so i resolved the problem via updating package.json file (with updatepackagejson.com) and run npm update.